# Why does samba client need to have INPUT port open?

Tags: samba

After I set up iptables INPUT policy to DROP on my *desktop*, my samba *client* there stoped working. I can understand that the samba server has to have some incoming ports opened, but why does client need it? And what ports does it need? All the advice I can find regarding firewall ports and samba are for server - does it apply to client too?

If I set INPUT policy to ACCEPT, then samba client is working again, so the problem has to be in the iptables config and also everything else on the desktop seems to be working ok. My relevant iptables settings:

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP
:FORWARD DROP
:OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d 127.0.0.0/8 ! -i lo -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Are you using DNS / IP addresses, or are you relying on legacy NBT for name resolution?

Comment: attach your rules with `iptables-save`

Comment: To debug just add `-j LOG` type rule as the last `INPUT` chain rule to see packets going to be dropped.

Comment: If the traffic is dropped in the INPUT chain you won't get any response. You can allow the local range i.e `192.168.0.0/16` on the INPUT chain

Comment: Because it needs to listen to NETBIOS ports and the like.  You can however find out what those ports are, and allow them through.

Comment: @sourcejedi I though that I'm using dns, but to my surprise when I used the raw IP address instead of server name, the log was quite different (much better looking) ending with NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE instead of NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL. Maybe I was just unknowingly used NBT name resolution before. However despite the different debug log and error messages the behavior stays the same - DROP policy = no connection, ACCEPT policy = connection ok.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Maybe your comment is the answer to the core question - can you elaborate more on why a _client_ has to _listen_ for something? Samba doesn't have simple client-server architecture?

Comment: @val0x00ff I have included the INPUT chain settings to show that established and related input is accepted.

Comment: Because it's required by the protocol.  Now, why does the protocol require that, well, that would be a question for Microsoft.